# How to change part of layout when clicked in IOS Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new in ios developer with swift programming language. How to change just the bottom layout. So, when Button A is clicked then button layout change and show A detail page like this image:

[image]

Comment: just hide and show one view to another view in button click action

Comment: are you have example for that? @JigarDarji

Comment: are you have example for that? @JigarDarji

Comment: give me your emaild i will create demo and send

Comment: pls check your mail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171919/discussion-between-jigar-darji-and-queen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pls find the attachment.i was added the demo in this link https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a756019d1e22e033385659e58a78fb0320180528133204/71142c04f6afb4855ba8366c5b6235f220180528133204/63d07c

Answer (score 0):

you can have 2 views over and underneath. On the top View place the buttons and on the bottom view design it for detail. When you click on the button just hide the top view.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to switch `ViewControllers` to do this. The best way is to do it programmatically so that it is all dynamic and you don't have to recreate the same thing over and over again. Below is some sample code that you can simply paste into your `ViewController` and should give you a good jumping off point. I did my best to add comments to the code, please me know in the comments if you have any questions on how it works.

**Code**

```
let btnTexts = ["A","B","C"] // List of buttons
let detailView = UIButton() // View which holds details. Made it a button too for simplicity.

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // This section bellow creates your buttons dynamically so if you change the list btnTexts it will automatically create buttons accordingly.
    var curH : CGFloat = 30 // Tracks the y coordinate of button to be inserted
    var tagCount = 0 // Tracks the tag of each button. This is used to retrieve the index of the one that is pressed.

    for btnText in btnTexts {
        let btn = UIButton() // Defines a button
        btn.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: curH, width: self.view.frame.width - 20, height: 50) // Sets position of button dynamically

        // More properties of the button defined below
        btn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        btn.layer.borderWidth = 1
        btn.setTitle("Button "+btnText, for: .normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)

        btn.tag = tagCount // Set tag of button
        self.view.addSubview(btn) // Adds button on screen (to the view)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showDetail(_:)), for: .touchUpInside) // Creates a target (action) when the button is pressed (touchUpInside)
        curH += 60 // Increment tracking of y coordinate of buttons
        tagCount += 1 // Increment tag of buttons
    }

    // Detail view is initialized off screen to it is originally hidden...
    detailView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    detailView.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
    detailView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - 30)
    self.view.addSubview(detailView)
    detailView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closeDetail(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

// When button is pressed, detailView is moved onscreen in an animation block
@objc func showDetail(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.detailView.setTitle( self.btnTexts[sender.tag] + " detail", for: .normal) // Retrieves name of the button from its tag to put text in the detailView
        self.detailView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 30, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - 30) // Sets detailView's new position
    }
}

// When detailView is pressed, detailView is moved offscreen in an animation block
@objc func closeDetail(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.detailView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - 30) // Sets detailView's new position
    }
}
```

**Demo**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its good idea to have a DetailViewController and reuse the same ViewController for all details Item. else add the height constrains and set it to zero based on requirement.